# Actionscript 2.0 XML get child by name

Tags: xml, actionscript-2

Now I'm porting some AS3.0 app to AS2.0 (don't ask me why :))
In AS3.0 I get child named "x" of my xml in a simple manner :

`xml.child("x").`

How can I get "x" node in AS2.0?
Of course, I can write a loop that enumerates children of xml and compares their names to "x".
But I hope there exists a simpler way...

Comment: unfortunately, you'll have to enumerate. you can encapsulate that logic into a function for resuse. or, as george suggests, you could try a 3rd party XML lib.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure, but it should be easier to use the [XPath API](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/documentation/en/flash/fl8/XpathAPI.pdf)(PDF link) in as2 instead of the default node looping. There should still be some forgotten [resources](http://blog.bittube.com/2006/06/21/the-dark-art-of-the-xpathapi/) out there on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing Excel file saved as XML 2003 
(after saving as xml, open in notepad and delete first two rows)

```
// XML
var main_xml:XML = new XML();
main_xml.ignoreWhite = true;
main_xml.load(_global.path + "main.xml"+_global.randomprm)
main_xml.onLoad = function(success) {
    var s:String = xmlValueOnPageByColTitleAndRow("your_worksheet_title", "cell_value_in_any_row_in_interested_column_OR_column_title_in_table", 2); // 2 - row number in table
    trace(s);
};

function xmlValueOnPageByColTitleAndRow(PageName:String, ColTitle:String, Row:Number) {
    var worksheet:XMLNode = xmlNodeByNameWithValue(main_xml.firstChild, "Worksheet", PageName);
    var column = xmlColumnByValue(worksheet, ColTitle);
    var rowNode:XMLNode = xmlNodeByNameWithOrder(worksheet, "Row", Row);
    var cell:XMLNode = xmlNodeByNameWithOrder(rowNode, "Cell", column);
    return cell.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
}

function xmlColumnByValue(node:XMLNode, Value:String) {
    if (node.firstChild.nodeName == "Cell") {
        var n = 0;
        for (var childnode:XMLNode = node.firstChild; childnode != null; childnode = childnode.nextSibling, n++) {
            if (childnode.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue == Value) return n;
        }
    } else 
    for (var childnode:XMLNode = node.firstChild; childnode != null; childnode = childnode.nextSibling) {
        res = xmlColumnByValue(childnode, Value); 
        if (res > -1) return res;
    }
    return -1;
}

function xmlNodeByNameWithOrder(node:XMLNode, Name:String, Order:Number) {
    var n = 0;
    for (var childnode:XMLNode = node.firstChild; childnode != null; childnode = childnode.nextSibling)
        if (childnode.nodeName == Name) {
            n++;
            if (n == Order) return childnode;
        }
    for (var childnode:XMLNode = node.firstChild; childnode != null; childnode = childnode.nextSibling) {
        finded = xmlNodeByNameWithOrder(childnode, Name, Order); 
        if (finded != NULL) return finded;
    }
    return NULL;
}

function xmlHasValue(node:XMLNode, Value:String) {
    for (attr in node.attributes) {
        if (node.attributes[attr] == Value) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function xmlNodeByNameWithValue(node:XMLNode, Name:String, Value:String) {
    if (node.nodeName == Name) {
        if (xmlHasValue(node, Value)) 
            return node;
        else 
            return null;
    } else {
        for (var childnode:XMLNode = node.firstChild; childnode != null; childnode = childnode.nextSibling) {
            finded = xmlNodeByNameWithValue(childnode, Name, Value); 
            if (finded != NULL) return finded;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

var depth = 0;
var str = "";
function traceAllChilds(node:XMLNode) {
    depth++;
    str = ""; for (var i=0; i<depth; i++) str = str + " ";
    if (node.nodeValue) trace(str + node.nodeName + " = " + node.nodeValue);
        else trace(str + node.nodeName);
    for (attr in node.attributes)
        trace (str + " [" + attr + " = " + node.attributes[attr]+"]");
    for (var childnode:XMLNode = node.firstChild; childnode != null; childnode = childnode.nextSibling)
        traceAllChilds(childnode); 
    str = ""; for (var i=0; i<depth; i++) str = str + " ";
    trace(str+""+ node.nodeName);
    depth--;
    return true;
}
```